# Setting max-width to details tag without effecting dropdown arrow

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```css
details {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3C3C3B;
}

details summary {
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/3/3907.svg) center no-repeat;
  color: transparent;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
}

details[open] summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/3/3581.svg) center no-repeat;
  color: transparent;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </summary>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
</details>
```

I don't want the text to flow over the area where the drop down arrow is. So that it appears something like this:

[image]

Setting `max-width` on `details` or `summary` won't work, since the arrow is styled on the `summary` tag. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could if you want to, just surround the text inside the `<summary>` tag with `<p>` tags and set the max width on them to whatever you want to

```css
details {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3C3C3B;
}

details summary {
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/3/3907.svg) center no-repeat;
  color: transparent;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
}

details[open] summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/3/3581.svg) center no-repeat;
  color: transparent;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
      <p style="max-width:70%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
      <p>
  </summary>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the width of the marker is known *in this instance*, we can just apply padding-right to anything after the `summary`.

```css
details {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3C3C3B;
  max-width: 80%;
}

details summary {
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/3/3907.svg) center no-repeat;
  color: transparent;
  width: 30px;
  /* known value*/
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
}

details[open] summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/3/3581.svg) center no-repeat;
  color: transparent;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
}

summary+* {
  padding-right: 30px;
  /* known value */
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </summary>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple to achieve what you want. You can make use of two important CSS functions for this:
1. Calc - calculate a value for a CSS property
2. vw - Vertical width of the viewport/screen

In your case, you can define the width of the paragraph in the details to have the width of the viewport minus the width of the arrow. Roughly, the arrow takes up around 50px of width(we can increase this if required). Subtract that from the viewport width and assign it to the p tag:

```
p { width: calc(100vw - 60px); }
```

https://codepen.io/venkat4541/pen/rELawd